# Notification for several seconds in notifications bar?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, android-notifications

how can i create a notification in the notifications bar that disappear after 5 seconds?
For example; this is the notification code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

// Build notification
// Actions are just fake
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText("This is a notification that didsappears in 5 seconds")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon)


NotificationManager notificationManager = 
  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Starting from this code how can i create my notification that disappear after 5 seconds?

Comment: Simply cancel the notification after five seconds.

Comment: Yeah this is what i want to do but i don't know where put the code and wich code use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `cancel(int id)` or `cancelAll()` to dismiss your notifications.
Start a timer for 5 seconds and when it ends call cancell();
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply cancel your notification after 5 seconds.For this you can use either `Timer` or `Handler`.Here is `Handler` solution:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 long delayInMilliseconds = 5000;
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        notificationManager.cancel(YourNotificationId);
    }}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

if you want to use Timer instead of `Handler`. Then you can try:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
   public void run()
   {
     notificationManager.cancel(YourNotificationId);
   }},delayInMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: @David_D This method will be called 5 seconds after you created a Notification.So of course yes.Or you mean smth else by "ongoing notification"?

Comment: i mean a permanent notification.. So, when the notification starts will be delated only after 5 seconds and not with a swipe over it. Do you understand?